# Install numpy latest package using apt-get

Tags: numpy, ubuntu

I used below query to install numpy package. But it installed 1.11.0 version. How to install the most recent version.

```
 sudo apt-get install python-numpy
```

Comment: You cannot do that in general. `apt-get` will only install a package from a distribution-based repository. One possible way in debian for instance, it to use "apt pinning" that will allow you to get a few packages from the development branch of debian. For Ubuntu, you can look if there is a "ppa". Else, any reason for not wanting to do `pip install --upgrade --user numpy` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo easy_install --upgrade numpy
```

Will simply do it fo you

Comment: I dont want to use pip. Can you suggest using apt-get

Comment: This is a terrible idea, which is why I downvoted. `sudo pip install` will on many systems install in the system tree for Python packages, clashing with the system-install NumPy and can make the system hard to debug.